# Do Not Populate auth_permission

Tags: django

When I do a syncdb, I do not want the auth_permission table to populate, or there are certain permissions I want to be able to "grant"  Example:  account | user | can_add_user is not a permission I need granted.

Can I eliminate these, and if so, how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
class MyModel(Models.model):
    Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
```

This only works in >= Django 1.7